# BigQuery/SQL: How do I use a column value as column name?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have these tables:

Foods

```
| food_id | title    |
| 1       | soy milk |
| 2       | banana   |
| 3       | apple    |
```

Nutrients

```
| food_id | nutrient_id | amount |
| 1       | n1          | 0.05   |
| 1       | n2          | 2      |
| 1       | n3          | 34     |
...
```

I need this:

```
| food_id | title    | n1   | n2 | n3 |
| 1       | soy milk | 0.05 | 2  | 34 |
| 2       | banana   |      |    |    |  
| 3       | apple    |      |    |    |
```

**The column titles should be represented by whatever found in `nutrient_id` column, not by actual strings "n1", "n2" etc. For example, if the nutrient id is "some-nutrient-123", then I want to see a column in results with the title "some-nutrient-123".**

`Struct` would also work.

I know all the joins, but can't wrap my head around this... how do I put the **value** of `nutrient_id` into a column title or a `Struct` key?

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39394111/dynamically-creating-columns-from-row-data-using-select-in-bigquery

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a query like:

```
with t1 as (
SELECT
  food_id as id_new,
  SUM(CASE WHEN nutrient_id = 'n1' THEN amount END) AS n1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN nutrient_id = 'n2' THEN amount END) AS n2,
  SUM(CASE WHEN nutrient_id = 'n3' THEN amount END) AS n3
FROM `<Nutrients>` 
GROUP BY id_new
ORDER BY id_new
)
SELECT * FROM `<Foods>` as t2 JOIN t1 
on t2.id = t1.id_new
```

Now, I understand that you do not want to hardcode the nutrient names. I am not certain if that is possible in BigQuery as of now. My workaround would be to run for example the query

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(
'SUM(CASE WHEN nutrient_id = "' , nutrient_id , '" THEN amount END) AS ', nutrient_id
    )
FROM (
  SELECT nutrient_id FROM <Nutrients> GROUP BY nutrient_id ORDER BY nutrient_id
)
```

following what is done in zealous [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39394111/dynamically-creating-columns-from-row-data-using-select-in-bigquery). This will give you all the cases to consider.